# JavaScript throws an exception, related to splicing - enemies[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript

So, I have this function, which for some reason at some point starts throwing an "enemies[i] is undefined" error. The function is constantly called in the game loop.

```
function moveEnemies() {

  for(i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].y += FE_SPEED;
    enemies[i].c.attr("y", friends[i].y);
    if(enemies[i].y > 640)
      delete enemies[i];
  }

  for(i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    if(!enemies[i])
      enemies.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `enemies.length` is a changing value since you call `delete enemies[i]` and `enemies.splice(i,1)`. You should instead keep changing a variable that updates the length of the list and break out of the loop when your loop counter is higher than this variable.

Comment: @stackErr: No it does not change from the `delete` call. Of course, he shouldn't be using `delete` at all, but that's another story.

Comment: @Bergi oops yes `delete` doesn't change it but `splice` does!

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate. The duplicate doesn't mention delete, and the question is not the same problem.  The answer may be similar, but the question seems unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are altering the array inside the for loop.

`enemies.splice(i, 1);`  is changing the length of the enemies

e.g.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.splice(1,2);

console.log( a.length ); // 2
```